# Variáveis são automaticamente executadas quando declaradas?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, se guardarmos um `setInterval()` em uma variável, ele já executa automaticamente mesmo sem aquela variável ter sido chamada em lugar nenhum?

Exemplo:

```js
let i = 0;
let myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(i++)
  if(i > 10){
    clearInterval(myInterval)
  }
},1000)
```

Eu nem chamei o `myInterval` em lugar nenhum e ele ja está executando...

Variáveis já são automaticamente executadas quando declaradas?

A dúvida mesmo é só porque na função temos que chamar a mesma em algum lugar, entendem?

Isso vale só pra JS ou pra todas as linguagens?

Comment: Para todas, pois é o comportamento da função. O que você atribuiu à variável não foi a função, foi o **retorno** da função; e para ter o retorno, a função será executada.

Comment: Assim como indicado na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) o retorno de `setInterval` é um valor númerico que identifica o *timer* criado para que possa mais tarde o desligar através da função `clearInterval`. Se não vai querer desligar o timer então também não precisa de capturar o retorno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) são estados e não ações, então não faz sentido em falar em execução de variáveis.

O que você fez foi chamar o `setInterval()`, isto basta. Como argumento passou uma ação, como ele espera. Sem a variável funciona da mesma forma, ela é completamente inútil neste código:

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  console.log(i++);
},1000)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Closure.js).

Comment: No caso eu coloquei a variável para um possível clearInterval.

Comment: Mas, entendi mais ou menos ainda, mesmo ela sendo executada, o valor era pra ficar na variavel e não ser executado; Desculpa a ignorância!

Comment: mas eu não sei disso, só posso responder em cima do que você postou. Você não entendeu o que o `setInterval()` faz então. Provavelmente quer fazer outra coisa, mas isso também não está na pergunta.

Comment: Perdão Maniero, foi so pra ilustrar mesmo que eu estava guardando a mesma. Sei que é inútil. Só ainda não bate o porque ela executa e não "guarda". De qualquer forma, obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: Acho que você não leu a resposta. A variável é inútil, ela não tem que guardar nada. Ele executa nada, como toda variável. Quem executa é a função. Se não é o que deseja faça outra coisa, o que está aí bate 100%.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta como mencionei acima, de qualquer forma, eu ainda não entendi; Não foi pela sua má explicação (Que foi muito boa), foi pela minha talvez falta de percepção e maturidade em JS ainda. Sei que ela executa, etc.. Mas pra mim, variáveis servem para guardar valores... Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Se você fizer `x = fatorial(5)`, você precisará *chamar* a função `x()` para obter o valor 120 ou o valor de `x` já será 120?

Comment: A variável não é inútil @Maniero, ela é o handler do seu interval. Que no caso, posteriormente você pode cancelá-lo:  `clearInterval(myInterval)`.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: Allan, antes estava sem o clearInterval. Mas é pra isso mesmo que eu usaria, mas não é culpa do Maniero, eu não coloquei toda a pergunta, desculpem!

Comment: Anderson, agora entendi melhor! O que me intriga é do porque ele mostrar o resultado no console, sendo que não estou usando a variável, apenas declarei a mesma.

Comment: Justamente porque a função `setInterval` é chamada para produzir o resultado que será atribuído à variável. Quando a função é executada, seu efeito é que a função passada por parâmetro seja executada no tempo especificado. Ter, ou não, a variável não mudará o comportamento da função - foi isso que o Maniero disse, não que ela fosse completamente inútil (cc @Allan).

Comment: @LucasCarvalho, respondendo sua pergunta, quando o setInterval é chamado, ele já executa tal função inciando o timer. A função retorna um handler para cancelá-lo posteriormente. É a mesma coisa que uma função assim: `function teste() { console.log("EXECUTEI"); return "valor-qualquer"; }`. Quando você atribuir a EXECUÇÃO dessa função a uma variável: `var a = teste();`, aparecerá no console `"EXECUTEI"` e sua variável tera o valor `"valor-qualquer"`.

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Com as explicações eu entendi agora! Value @Allan

Comment: @LucasCarvalho primeiro, editar a pergunta depois de ter sido respondida não é legal. Se continuar fazendo isso desestimula as pessoas responderem suas perguntas porque pode invalidar a resposta dada. O que mudou importa zero, não vou mudar minhas resposta, mas eu poderia mudar isso nela e continuar sem, a variável. Eu não sei se consigo explicar de outra forma, pra mim é óbvio demais para conseguir tentar explicar melhor. Como uma amigo meu que dá aula na Unicamp diz "eu não sei explicar para o aluno o que é uma mesa"

Comment: Talvez lhe falte conhecimento anterior para entender a diferença entre cada coisa, ou seja está fazendo algo muito mais avançado do que é capaz neste momento. Não é questão de entender JS, é entender o que cada coisa é em programação, um erro que vejo as pessoas cometerem. Querem ver resultado e não se preocupam em aprender de fato antes de fazer. Eu repeti diversas vezes que variável serva para guardar valores, por isso eu tirei a variável para mostrar que ela não serve para nada, afinal você não está guardando valor ali.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é porque você não declarou a variável com a função, apenas o retorno desta.
O seu código deveria ser:

```
let i = 0;
let myInterval = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log(i++)
      if(i > 10){
        clearInterval(myInterval)
      }
    },1000)
}
```

Sendo assim, apenas ao chamar explicitamente:

```
myInterval()
```

O setInterval será executado.

Comment: Neste caso `myInterval` não será o retorno de `setInterval`, então não faria sentido coloca-lo no `clearInterval`; a menos que faltou um *return* do retorno do `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Você está salvando na variável o retorno da função `setInterval`, você pode armazenar a função dessa forma:

```
let interval = setInterval
```

E depois você executa chamando o nome da função mais os parênteses

```
interval()
```

```js
let interval = setInterval
let c = null
let i = 0

let funToExecute = function() {
    console.log(i)
    i++
    if (i > 10) {clearInterval(c)}
}

c = interval(funToExecute, 1000)
```